# SpriteBuilder doesn't publish assets

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have updated the spritebuilder to the new version. The spritebuilder doesn't publish the images/fonts. I can add and delete images in my SB project and when I click publish nothing happens. If I delete the files in the Published-iOs folder and then click publish on SB this folder will only contain the .ccbi files.

This bug is delaying my whole project please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that under File -> Project Settings the checkbox for "Only publish ccb-files" is unchecked.

Also double-check the publish directories in the same dialog, in case the files are simply being published to the wrong folder.

If that doesn't help try File -> Clean Cache to force SpriteBuilder to re-publish everything.

Comment: such a simple thing and I was loosing my mind. You're a life saver thanks.

Comment: If that was life-saving you must be under a **lot** of pressure from your client. ;)